# Drawing to canvas is too slow , How do i achieve constant 30 fps or more ? (Android)

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, frame-rate

I'm trying to create a 2d game for Android and for the moment I'm struggling with achieving a constant fps of about 30 fps (i think 30 is enough for a mobile game). I am using SurfaceView and a pretty straight forward game loop:

```
 while (isOk==true)
    {
        if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) continue;

        c = holder.lockCanvas();

        update();
        draw(c);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

        t2= System.currentTimeMillis();
        all++;
        if ( mspf /* miliseconds per frame, and it's set to 1000/30 */ -(t2-t1)  > 0 )
        {
            try {
                t.sleep(mspf-(t2-t1));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
                Log.w("Super",String.valueOf(mspf-(t2-t1))+ " o " + String.valueOf(++total)+ "out of " +String.valueOf(all));

        t1=Math.max( t1+mspf, t2);
    }
```

This is the game loop . As you may have noticed , I use that Log.w to see in how many frames i have some remaining time to Thread.sleep . The results are not that great . I have about 10-25% of the frames that exceede 1000/30 ms to run:

> 09-07 00:00:39.069: W/Super(28328): -1 o 4395out of 16353
>   09-07 00:00:39.109: W/Super(28328): -1 o 4396out of 16354
>   09-07 00:00:39.209: W/Super(28328):  0 o 4397out of 16357
>   09-07 00:00:40.269: W/Super(28328): -4 o 4398out of 16389
>   09-07 00:00:40.299: W/Super(28328): -3 o 4399out of 16390
>   09-07 00:00:40.339: W/Super(28328): -4 o 4400out of 16391
>   09-07 00:00:40.379: W/Super(28328): -4 o 4401out of 16392
>   09-07 00:00:40.409: W/Super(28328): -5 o 4402out of 16393
>   09-07 00:00:40.459: W/Super(28328): -8 o 4403out of 16394
>   09-07 00:00:40.499: W/Super(28328): -7 o 4404out of 16395
>   09-07 00:00:40.529: W/Super(28328): -3 o 4405out of 16396
>   09-07 00:00:40.569: W/Super(28328): -5 o 4406out of 16397
>   09-07 00:00:40.609: W/Super(28328): -5 o 4407out of 16398
>   09-07 00:00:40.639: W/Super(28328): -3 o 4408out of 16399
>   09-07 00:00:40.679: W/Super(28328): -3 o 4409out of 16400
>   09-07 00:00:40.719: W/Super(28328): -4 o 4410out of 16401

In draw , i don't have so many bitmaps to draw. ( about 15 bitmaps, including a shader , a transparency mask for some effect  and a scaling ) . All the bitmaps are loaded in the create method from resources (only PNG file).

```
public void draw(Canvas c)
{


    c.drawBitmap(background,0,0,null);
    c.drawBitmap(m_image.get(m_cn),400 , 100, test);


    c.drawBitmap(start_menu,10 ,10 , test);
    c.drawBitmap(inventory_menu, 200 , 10, test);
    c.drawBitmap(shop_menu,400  , 10, test);
    c.drawBitmap(options_menu, 10 , 300, test);
    c.drawBitmap(facebook_menu,200 , 300, test);





    light.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.CLEAR);


    light_matrix.setScale(scale_factor, scale_factor);
    light_matrix.postTranslate(light_x-mask_aux.getWidth()/2*scale_factor, light_y-mask_aux.getHeight()/2*scale_factor);
    light.drawBitmap(mask_aux, light_matrix, test);


    copy_the_screen.drawBitmap(buffer.get(b_activ),0,0,test);
    sh =  new BitmapShader(screen_copy,Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    pnt.setShader(sh);

    c.drawARGB(200, 0, 0,0);
    c.drawBitmap(mask,0,0 ,pnt);


}
```

The update method means nothing to the complexity , so there has be something to be done in these 2 functions  in order to achieve a better fps . Help me , pls and excuse me for my bad english.

Ok . The update function is this :

```
     public void update()
{
    m_time++;
    if (m_time==2)
    {
        m_time=0;
        m_cn++;
        if (m_cn==4)m_cn=0; 
    }

    if (touched==true)
    {
        light_x=t_x;
        light_y=t_y;
        scale_factor=t_y/150;
    }
}
```

It only modifies the bitmap i choose from a sprite . I don't have a big bitmap with all the position of a character , but 4 different bitmaps. The second "if" refers to a mask image that creates a ball of light exactly where i touch . I use that light_matrix to scale that light-ball proportional to the Y - coordinate ( of the click event) . That is why I use the shader , to create the light effect . Here, take a look on the OnTouchEvent :

```
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //I put this sleep method here because I noticed it was the lagging the game if i let it run 
    // without a sleep.
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     // after sleep , i only check for events.

 }
```

Comment: Is this on an emulator or a device?

Comment: I am using `SurfaceView` and I've made many 2D games so far without a problem, I have some theories to why this is happening but I'm not very sure, if you could post your 'update()' method and also describe what 'light' and 'light_matrix' is I'll be able to post an answer

Comment: @TomTsagk

I added in the post the info you wanted.

Comment: @MikeM. I run it directly on a device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another answer is working to optimize your code, so I will leave that and talk about using some different approaches.

When you render on a SurfaceView's surface with Canvas, all rendering is performed in software.  As displays get more pixels, your app will have to touch more and more memory, and it's going to get slower.  You can avoid this by setting a fixed size for the surface with `setFixedSize()` -- see the "hardware scaler exerciser" activity in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) for an example.

You'll get much better performance by using the GPU.  For a SurfaceView surface, that means using OpenGL ES.  There are a number of tutorials on the web; for a simple example of a 2D game written with GLES, see [Android Breakout](https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/).  Most of the examples in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) are GLES2 based.  (The Grafika GLES code is factored better for reuse.  At some point it makes sense to just use an open-source game engine.)

Using sleep calls in game loops, and assuming that you'll get a reliable frame rate, is generally a bad idea.  For an explanation and recommendations on alternatives, see the "[game loops](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#loops)" section of the Android System-Level Graphics Architecture doc.  The section on the SurfaceView lifecycle may also be of use.

Comment: that setFIxedSize() helped me, but it's not enough . Still, I'm sure i'm going to find the solution in the links you sent me . About the sleep method, i was sure that this isn't the right way to do it , but I couldn't find any other solution that didn't use it . I will read these alternatives you provided me with and I'll come with a feedback as soon as I can. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

First of all it's bad technique  to create new objects each frame, so take this line:

```
sh =  new BitmapShader(screen_copy,Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
```

and move it to the constructor (or at a place where you initialize your game), I'm not sure if you need to change `BitmapShader` each frame because screen_copy changes, but if there is a way to avoid making a new one each frame it's the best.

```
private BitmapShader sh;

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    //...

    sh =  new BitmapShader(screen_copy,Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
}
```

The rest of the draw method looks fine.

the `onTouchEvent` looks strange, I'm not sure why you would use a `Thread.sleep(int)` there, but I doubt that's a big issue.

Now that I take a closer look at your main loop it looks a little odd, especially this line

```
t1=Math.max( t1+mspf, t2);
```

I think this is the reason everything is happening, let me re-write your main loop, you can try it and tell me the results

```
while (isOk) /*you can skip the "==true" part*/
{
    if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) continue;

    //Start Frame
    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    //Canvas and drawing
    c = holder.lockCanvas();

    update();
    draw(c);
    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

    //End Frame
    t2= System.currentTimeMillis();
    all++;
    if ( t2 -t1 > mspf )
    {
        try {t.sleep(mspf-(t2-t1));} 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    else
        Log.w("Super",String.valueOf(mspf-(t2-t1))+ " o " + String.valueOf(++total)+ "out of " +String.valueOf(all));
}
```

Comment: I cannot stop recreating the BitmapShader because as u have guessed that parameter changes almost every frame . I tried that with t1 and t2 , but didn't receive any better results . Thanks , anyway.